# Home server bottleneck (filesystem server)

Tags: filesystems, nfs, virtual-machine, file-sharing, sshfs

I am trying to set up a filesystem server, so that I can use my various laptops to transparently mount a directory containing many VirtualBox VMs, some of which run full graphics environments.
I will have up to 10 headless VMs running concurrently (as well as one at a time with display)

I plan on using this server for also serving home directories and media folders (with HD video and music) to a few machines.
All of it should be transparent (fast, and appear to my Linux systems as though it is local).  I plan on using a combination of NFS4 and SSHFS, and connecting to the fs server with Wireless LAN.

Currently, I'm using a RaspberryPi I had lying around, and It sort-of works for serving the music/video (the VMs run, but they are very slow, I'm not even gonna try the home directories).

Is there a way to tune sshfs, or VirtualBox itself, to cache, page (or whatever) the VMs locally in a more efficient way for the task at hand?
Perhaps somebody can give me some tips on picking out server hardware that's budget friendly?

P.S. The wireless router is pretty fast ASUS RT-AC66U, so I think I won't have a problem there.. and ALL of the files I wan't to serve are currently on a 2TB external hard-drive.

EDIT --

So basically, what I'm getting from everybody is that I need a significant portion of the combined size of the Virtual disk images in RAM (or is it disk cache?) on the file server, so at that point my bottleneck becomes the wireless network (and relevant components like cards/adapters)? Also, is there a way to tune the RAM on a Linux machine to favor the virtual disk images (or any specific files) over other freeable memory?

Comment: If you've got WIFI AC then - if your external drive is a USB 2.0 - your bottleneck will probably be the disk connection. Getting it in an eSATA/USB 3 enclosure could alleviate that a great deal - but all of those external hdds are usually WD Greens or equivalent - economy class disks. You'll want some redundancy at least.

Comment: Mounting over a volatile connection such as wifi sounds like a dangerous idea. NFS is robust in a way that it just blocks and freezes until the connection is up again, but sshfs will probably drop the connection.

The bottleneck are probably the virtual machines. A virtual hard drive image is frequently accessed all across the file (the file contains an entire fs with all its complexity) and driving this over an encrypted layer (ssh + probably wifi) and with the standard wifi delay sounds terrible. VM should probably be loaded into a ramfs on the laptop.

Comment: Really, I think the bottle neck for hosting virtual machines on a raspberry pi is the CPU--it's single threaded.  This means that each of your VM's is contending with each other, the rest of the server processes, and the kernel for CPU time on the single core.  Make sure that there's a real server core backing each of your virtual cores.  Also, the memory size is low, so your disk cache is also going to be small, so you'll spend more time then normal doing disk I/O, which is super slow over USB.  If you have a place for one, you can buy cheap server refurbs off ebay--like a DL360 G5.

Comment: @ChristopherNeylan - wow. Totally missed the dev board angle - definitely wont work. serving 10 concurrent encrypted FUSE mounts will explode it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. a) the pi is only a temporary solution until I figure out what kind of server hardware I need without being wasteful b) And I'm not actually hosting VMs on the pi, I'm hosting a file server mounted over the network where clients mounting the fs containing virtual machines are actually 'hosting' the VMs.  now @orion yeah, I figured the ssh encryption was going to add significantly to the load.  sshfs actually does have some features to maintain and reconnect to mounts.  How much is a file server bound by CPU (other than encryption of ssh)?

Comment: CPU won't be a bottleneck when you switch from pi to a workstation. The main necessities are high-throughput physical storage (a few GB of ram for filesystem caching + a 7200 rpm hard drive should be enough for any home system) and of course a high-bandwidth low-latency LAN. If you use wireless, I don't think the rest matters at all. My brother is using a <$200 desktop with an old i3 CPU and 4G ram for serving data storage over wire to 5 other computers (including vm's) without any trouble at all. The weak link in your case will be the network.

Comment: @orion - i disagree there. sshfs is a FUSE filesystem and is therefore neither reliable nor performant. Opting for FUSE is almost definitely not a good idea - especially considering asker is running live VMs over the mount. And wifi AC is *very fast*.  Theoretically it performs better than SATA3. But at least should keep up w/ a 100mbit link.

Comment: Shane - actually, thinking about it, there is probably a far more capable linux/bsd file server in your router than there is in your Pi. And i'll bet it has a USB 3 port or two available to you. Youd likely do much better serving from it - and may even be able to hack on it a bit and get root access. FUSE will still suck, of course, but a few NFS-served vms should serve tolerably well.

Comment: I never recommended sshfs, I agree it's more of a hack. NFS would be the way to go, as it is more robust and made properly on the inside. I haven't had much experience with the newest wifi standard, but what concerns me the most is that the connection can degrade unexpectedly: even the fastest connection can experience unexpected lag, dropped packets, or down time for any reason. But I'll be glad if I'm proved wrong, I have trust issues with wifi.

Comment: @orion - I doubt very seriously that you will, but with sufficient caching and a proper fs there won't be any danger in it. *Tolerably well* is all I will hazard there. But given the USB 2, Pi board, and FUSE, I just think wifi AC is probably not the most likely culprit.

Comment: @mikeserv I don't feel comfortable hacking on the router itself.. I don't have experience with embedded systems, and no clue about how I could get into the system (BusyBox) and install programs/subsystems or hack on the config files.  There is a fileserver built into the router, but I don't feel like using it if I can't have total administrative control.. Plus, the whole building would be out of internet access if I fuc**ed it up

Answer (score 0):

There is no single bottleneck. 
It's a stack of layers that each make it impossible.

If you really need what you ask for, start again and expect to spend quite 
some money. Also, you may read some more about the technologies you use, to get a feeling for what may work together or not.

But then, I think you may not actually need what you describe. For example, you may not need network access as fast as if it were local.